# How to use Yasnippet printf

Tags: c++, emacs, yasnippet

I recently watched [this fantastic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmBovJvQ3KU) on how to use Yasnippet in Emacs.

#### Can someone explain how to use this snippet?

Specifically, what are the `if` and `string-match` elisp conditionals/functions doing in regards to the intended use of this snippet?

This snippet is found in Yasnippet **c++-mode** > printf.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: printf
# key: printf
# --
printf("${1:%s}\\n"${1:$(if (string-match "%" yas-text) ", " "\);")
}$2${1:$(if (string-match "%" yas-text) "\);" "")}
```

Comment: the `$2` isn't conditional - it has no effect on the `$1` parameter.  Fields that have the form `${<num>:$(...)}` are conditional on previous fields with matching `num` and `yas-text` is bound to the value of the first `${1}` field while the contained elisp is evaluated.  So, here, both the mirrored fields (with elisp code) are conditional on the first `${1:"%s"}` as explained below

Comment: The question seems too broad. Can you pose a more specific question, e.g. about how to use `if` or `string-match`, or whatever specific how-to you're wondering about?

Comment: Please refrain from using images, instead of code. Here is a [list of reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3578036).

Comment: @JustCarty - I've edited the question based on your suggestions. Can you please reopen this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it should work if you can load it into the mode properly (there are a few yasnippet modes that failed to load properly for me -- if all else fails, in the snippet file itself use `M-x yas-load-snippet-buffer` and see if that works.)

As for the macro, the second argument is basically conditional on the first one containing a "%" sign.  If it does, then a comma is inserted after the closing quote and you jump there hitting tab from the string you are editing.  If it does not contain a % anywhere in it, then it's removed.  In other words:

If you type "hello world" into the first parameter (the string) with no %s you get:

```
printf("hello world\n");
```

with no second value to fill in.  However, if you add a %s, you'll get the cursor placed after the `,` to fill in the second when you hit tab (where I typed CURSORHERE):

```
printf("hello %s\n", CURSORHERE));
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes so much more sense. This is fantastic, thanks much.